# Can't center inline-block element in parent

Tags: css, display, displaymode

So i'm having trouble entering the element with the `middle` class. So the container `box-block-head-yellow` had a width of 100% so that it can span any container, the class `middle` is using display inline-block so that the container wraps around it's content you can see the markup below.

```
<!-- Markup for container -->
<div class="box">
 <div class="box-block-head-yellow">
  <div class="box-title-block middle">
   <h1 class="box-title">Latest projects</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So the issue i'm having is the middle container isn't centering in the middle. With the following styles on each element.

Parent element
[image: Parent element]

Child element
[image: Child element]

Result of element not being entered horizontally
[image: Result element]

Comment: Can you write out what the css is for the classes instead of a very blurry picture? Or at least just the main css components of the divs?

Comment: a link to js-fiddle / codepen would help as well!

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following CSS to your box-block-head-yellow class can solve the center alignment issue.

```css
.box-block-head-yellow {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.middle {
  display: inline-block;
}
```